# How do I return array data from a foreach loop in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm looping through a nested object to get a some data. This is working, but I can't seem to return the data and use it elsewhere.

I've tried putting the loop in a promise and couldn't get anywhere either. What am I doing wrong?

```
data: any = {
    '1234': {
        url: 'https://example1.com/',
        path: 'uploads',
        link: 'https://example1.com/uploads',
    },
    '5678': {
        url: 'https://example2.com/',
        path: 'uploads',
        link: 'https://example2.com/uploads',
    }
}


onSubmit(formData) {

    this.formdata = formData;

    Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
        if (key == this.formdata.pin) {
            const url = this.data[key].url;
            // have also tried this.url to no avail
        }
    });

    // says undefined
    console.log(url);

    // set up headers, etc...

    // I need to use here
    this.http.post(url, body, head)
    ...
}
```

Comment: use map() instead of forEach()

Comment: `url` is undefined in your above example as it is limited in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onSubmit(formData) {

this.formdata = formData;
let url; // Define here so that its accessible
Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
    if (key === this.formdata.pin) {
         url = this.data[key].url;
        // have also tried this.url to no avail
    }
});

// Now url is in scope
console.log(url);

    ...
}
```

Comment: This solution moves `url` to the `onSubmit` block scope and can therefore be used/accessed in your `console.log` statement

Answer (score 1):

Switching your `forEach` to a `map` can simplify this; `map` return values, whereas `forEach` does not.

Old:

```
Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
    if (key == this.formdata.pin) {
        const url = this.data[key].url;
    }
});

// says undefined
console.log(url);
```

New: (I've also added a `===` in here based on the comment below)

```
const urls = Object.keys(this.data).map(key => {
    if (key === this.formdata.pin) {
        return this.data[key].url;
        // have also tried this.url to no avail
    }
});

console.log(urls);
```

[map docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [forEach docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Better to use `===` than `==`